# Risk tolerance questionnaire

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I would like to create a risk tolerance database where I render the questionnaire to users, like [this](https://www.calcxml.com/calculators/inv08). What I've achieved so far:
[image]

Regarding answer table:

- Each answer has specific points
- One question's appearance may depend on another question's answer
- One answer may depend on another question's answer

Regarding question type:

- There are 2 question types: input (number) and radio (multi/multiple choice)
- Input type is basically a number while multi is multiple choice
- We determine the points for the amount chosen for Input field by using lower/higher bound percentage. i.e: if the max amount is 150000, then choosing 75000 means 50%, which is between lower bound 40% and higher bound 50%.

**A complex example:**
[image]

This questionnaire is to determine what kind of investor a user is, backend will collect the points at the end of the survey, calculate them and return the correspondent type.
My question is, how will I create a table in a way that satisfies the given complexity? i.e: an answer depending on another question's answer, a question's appearance depending on another answer, etc.

Database used: MySQL - phpMyAdmin

Comment: ok, silly question, what would happen if you had 2 answers that determined the points of another answer, e.g. the age could score alter the score of answer "save for retirement" but also the "average income" (making things up here) could modify that same answer to a different value? Or is that a unique relationship between answers?

Comment: @apokryfos The relationship could be between 3 questions, possibly.

Comment: Um, could one option be: question_id,answer,age_range,score ? Also, conceptually, all questions can be multiple choice. Just that sometimes the choice is 1.

Comment: @Strawberry You mean just a simple question/answer and we check the corresponding point? Yes.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - but that doesn't sound quite right

Comment: @Strawberry I didn't get what you meant, sorry. Yes, I'm using "input/multi" so I could determine whether a question should show up as range/input (number) or multi-choice. Input question type will have lower/higher bound, check the post I've explained it.

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key.

Comment: What does 'what is the logic behind building an "answer" table?' mean? Please use enough words & sentences to be clear. Putting words in quotes when you have a special meaning for them that you have not made clear does not make the special meaning clear. And it shows you know that you weren't clear.

Comment: It just seems like an unecessary check. Either a question has more than one possible answer, in which case it's multi, or it doesn't, in which case it's input. The boolean is redundant.

Comment: @philipxy i.e the logic of creating the answer table in a way that satisfies the conditions. The diagram is for demonstration, I'm not asking anyone to write mysql codes or anything, just asking if one could point out what I can do.

Comment: @Strawberry A question always has multiple answers, we don't store the "input text" we get from the client, we take the text and determine which bounderies it belonds to (between 10%-20%, 20%-30%, etc)

Comment: What does "the logic of" mean? What is the answer like to a question that asks for the logic of? (Rhetorical.) I still don't know what you are trying to ask, you again haven't said it. Please be clear. Please clarify via post edits not comments. What is the name & edition of your information modeling & database design textbook? Where do you get following it here?

Comment: Ok now please fix "satisfies the given complexity ...".

Comment: @philipxy I did! I gave examples of complexity... Please also check the attached link, this: https://www.calcxml.com/calculators/inv08

Comment: Please don't use links & don't use comments to clarify.

Comment: @philipxy I edited the question to further clarify what I'm asking help for, I can't be clearer than this, I gave some examples and even another link (inside the post) that shows what the questionnaire will look like.